# Eclipse C++ plugin to view assembler?

Tags: c++, eclipse

Does a C++ plugin exist for Eclipse where you can see the assembler produced?

EDIT: I did check google but could only find ARM results and nothing looking like a solic eclipse plugin.

Comment: There's a [Dissassembly View](http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.cdt.doc.user/reference/cdt_u_dissassembly_view.htm) that will show you the assembly language of the program you're debugging mixed with the C source – maybe that would be sufficient?

Comment: Hey thanks- got it! Just a small question, I click Run -> Debug and when I am looking at the assembly, it keeps scrolling forever (as if I had infinite assembly), yet my program is just a hello world test. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Sorry, no idea. I stumbled on that by searching the Eclipse docs to see if there's anything, I haven't actually used it.

Comment: No prob, will ask on here as google didnt turn anything up